# window.close how to close the current window in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

hi this is my current code where i have popup once i cancel the popup i have to close the entire app tab which means the window

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
      var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

          /* Note: The hard coded user object has been commented out, as 
             it is now passed as an object parameter from the HTML template.
          */
          /* $scope.user = {
              user: 'name',
              password: null
          };*/

          $scope.open = function (user) {
              $scope.user = user;
              $modal.open({
                  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                  backdrop: true,
                  windowClass: 'modal',
                  controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, user) {
                      $scope.user = user;
                      $scope.submit = function () {
                          $log.log('Submiting user info.');
                          $log.log(JSON.stringify(user));
                          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                      }
                      $scope.cancel = function () {
                          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                         window.open('location', '_self', '');
                        window.close();
                      };
                  },
                  resolve: {
                      user: function () {
                          return $scope.user;
                      }
                  }
              });
          };
      };  
  </script>

  <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
      <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
          </div>
          <form ng-submit="submit()">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <label>User name</label>
              <input type="text" ng-model="user.user" />
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" ng-model="user.password" />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn primary-btn" value="Submit" />
            </div>
          </form>
      </script>

      <button class="btn" ng-click="open({user: 'username', password: 'password'})">Open me!</button>
      <div ng-show="user.password">Got back from modal: {{ user | json}}</div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

this code not working any help please

window.close() not working

Comment: please refer to http://plnkr.co/edit/d1VhZhjdBPPEHn2sVJBK?p=preview

Comment: comeon read my question i said need to close the window not the popup

Comment: what error does it throw?

Comment: that i gave my code to check , no error

Comment: could you please have a try to use $window.close()?

Comment: @gayathri I could not get you want to close the modal or close the window

Answer (score 2):

`window.close` will only close the windows opened by application and not the windows/tabs opened by user. that means when user visits your site HE/SHE OPENED the window and not your app. but if u open a new window using javascript using `window.open` you can close with `window.close`. This is done for security reasons and is inbuilt in almost all latest browsers.

Comment: check mycode before the answer i tried its not working

Comment: whts the solution the above one is not an answer

Comment: i checked. thats what i am saying you are opening the new window in the same window the user opened using  '_self'. that window is not opened by your app.

Comment: can u create a fiddle for my question with answer use my above code

Answer (score 0):

use `$window.close()` in [$window](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service.

You are asking about angular modal.
use this

```
$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel'); or $modalInstance.close();
```

read this for more information [modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)